# in Titanium for iPhone, how to transition from table view to detail view.?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, titanium

I have created a table view and want that when i click a cell then a new window should appear and my cell data should be displayed in that window!!!!....

here my code goes...

```
var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView(
{
    data:[
        {title:"Row 1 - simple row"},
        {title:"Row 2 - Having child", hasChild:true},
        {title:"Row 3 - with Details",hasDetail:true},
        {title:"Row 4 - with Check",hasCheck:true},
        {title:"Row 5 - red background",backgroundColor:"#f00"}
    ]
});

table1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.rowData)
    {
        var win5 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            //url:e.rowData.test,
            title:e.rowData.title
        });
        win5.open();
    }
})

win1.add(table1);
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Does the detail view doesnt open or detail text is not getting transferred on the new view?

Comment: When i click on the cell.. the simulator gets hang....

Comment: I feel that the filepath or url which you are specifying has a problem.

Comment: Is your file directly in your ressources folder or do u have the file under some sub-folder?

Comment: Can you please post the code about how to pass the file path or url?

Comment: i am only having the default project that titanium creates when we select Titanium Mobile Development.. I am only having app.js file and inside that Two tabs in first tab i am using this instead of default label given.  I am simply replacing label code to this one.. It is showing me table in simulator but when i click cell  the simulator stops working with my code... i have still not tried your code due to lack of time ... but will let u know about that.. ....

Comment: For using Tabs instead of windows, TabGroup's open method requires to be called. You do not need to call Window's Open method. This would work for you provided that you give proper url

Comment: i have found one of the link for passing url : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/96441/passing-row-data-to-new-widow

Comment: ok so did you get your answer.

Comment: Thats fine. You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView(
{
data:[
    {title:"Row 1 - simple row", url:"<Specify the whole path of your detail.js file>"},
    {title:"Row 2 - Having child", hasChild:true, url:"<Specify the whole path of your detail.js file>"},
    {title:"Row 3 - with Details",hasDetail:true, url:"<Specify the whole path of your detail.js file>"},
    {title:"Row 4 - with Check",hasCheck:true, url:"<Specify the whole path of your detail.js file>"},
    {title:"Row 5 - red background",backgroundColor:"#f00", url:"<Specify the whole path of your detail.js file>"}
]
});

table1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (e.rowData)
{
    var win5 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:e.rowData.url,
        title:e.rowData.title
    });
    win5.open({animated:true});

}
})

win1.add(table1);
```

Hope this helps you.